# x-axis dates not showing up on matplotlib when importing data from pandas DataReader

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-datareader

I'm using pandas DataReader to graph stock charts in matplotlib, but the dates don't show up on the x-axis when I use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web

start = datetime(2014,1,1)
end = datetime(2018,9,27)
spy = web.DataReader('SPY','iex',start,end)
spy['open'].plot(xlim=['2018-01-01','2018-02-28'])
```

Result: 
[Chart of SPY with no x-axis dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UABUy.png)

However, when I import the same data from csv using the following command, the dates show up just fine when I plot the data:

```
spy_csv = pd.read_csv('spy.csv',index_col='date',parse_dates=True)
```

I'm assuming the "parse_dates=True" is making the difference, so I'm wondering if there is an equivalent command when importing from DataReader. What would that equivalent look like in my DataReader code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your index to `datetime` format

```
spy.index=pd.to_datetime(spy.index)
```

Then , pass the xlim by using `Timestamp`

```
spy['open'].plot(xlim=[pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('2018-02-28')])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks your code worked. I needed to convert my index using 'to_datetime()'. However, I found that adding pd.Timestamp did not affect the graph, but I'm happy with the coding.